# Does the amount of space an index on varchar(100) takes up depend on the length of the value stored?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this question has been asked before.

I was thinking of putting an index on a field of `VARCHAR(100)`.  Does an index on 'foo' take up less space than an index on 'foobar123'?

Comment: Yes, you have any concern on the disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space required will be more as the value is used for indexing.

But since it is compressed I dont think there would be a huge performance impact.